# Exporting font (labels) on qgis2web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I am using QGIS and qgis2web to make a simple historical map. I have many problems because I am an amateur, but I am solving them through a search.

But as you can see in the picture, I have a problem with my font now!

[image]
China is output properly set to 'points' but other countries are set to 'map units' and are not output properly!

I made the font type 'Points' at first, and it worked well on qgis2web. Second, I used 'Meters at scale' but it didn't work normally. I searched and found that qgis2web does not yet support Metres at Scale, and instead, Map units will work.

So I tried setting it as 'Map units' for the last time, and it doesn't work as well. I want to make the font small when zoom out and big when zoom in. So I used Map units... :(

What should I do?

Oh, I'd like to ask you another question. I set up a font separately, but qgis2web wiki explains 'The export only specifies which font a label uses - it does not export the font itself'! I tried to put the .woff2 fonts file in the webfonts folder, but it doesn't work properly.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you let us know which export format you are using in qgis2web? The export routines for Leaflet, OpenLayers, and Mapbox GL JS are all different, and each has different capabilities.

Comment: @TomChadwin Oh, hello, developer! I use openlayers. Leaflet has errors where polygons no longer appear when I turn the map screen to the right (or left). (That's what happens when I rotate the earth once.) So I don't use it.

Comment: @TomChadwin In addition, the scale-based visibility of the layer itself works well, but the scale-based visibility of the labels - rendering does not work. Is it normal?